# Migration to Magento2.4.4

Tags: magento, migration, magento2.4

I have some questions about the migration to 2.4.4 of magento.
I am a Webmaster. Currently our site is Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1 and I would like to have your opinion on the repercussions of not migrating to 2.4.4.
What will be the disadvantages and the positive points.

Thank you very much for your help

Germain

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave you the [Magento 2.4.4 Release Notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-4.html). This should help you in terms of knowing all the changes.

I think one of the best updates is the **GraphQL** improvements.

If you are using the **Enterprise Edition** i think it's a good idea to use the [Upgrade Compatibility Tool](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/use-upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html) which helps you identify the changes you'll need to make in order to upgrade your Magento version without problems.

I wish I've helped you.